# closedness of compact sets in some topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is there any famous axiom on X other than Hausdorffness or axioms leading to Hausdorffness,such that every compact set in X is closed?

Comment: No, to the best of my knowledge. Such spaces have come to be called $KC$-spaces, and there have been quite a few questions asked about them here over the last couple of years. (They have also been called $T_B$-spaces.)

Comment: As far I know, no. And I believe that if this axiom were famous, I should know about it.

Comment: I was convinced that this was called  $T_{1\frac {1}{2}}$, but when I tried to find a reference I couldn't.